# Android - Edge detection on mobile

Tags: java, android, edge-detection

I am working on android SDK using JAVA as base programming language. One of the requirement is that I need to perform edge detection on an image. Is there any third party api that can be integrated with my development code.

Any free or paid api is appreciated.

Regards,
Puneet

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this URL](http://www.3programmers.com/mwells/documents/pdf/Final%20Report.pdf).

The author has used Sobel operator for edge detection.